# ImageIO.Read not working most of the time?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I want to display an image from a URL Java using swing. I use this code:

```
BufferedImage pic = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://www.swpc.noaa.gov/SWN/g_curr.gif"));
JLabel label1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(pic));
label1.setBounds(200,28,32,12);
jp.add(label1); //jp is a JPanel.
```

About one forth of the time it works. The other times nothing is shown, and no exception is thrown.

Comment: Are you sure that it's `ImageIO.read(...)`'s fault? I doubt that this is the case. Perhaps it's something more elementary such as your setting bounds on your label?

Comment: Is the server in question working properly, better not put `ImageIO` to the stands, instead question the server, is it working properly ?

Comment: Please do have a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113159/background-image-in-a-nested-jpanel/11113479#11113479), if my computer is working, since it's the server, than you can surely see the image.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a `JFrame` and then add your `JPanel` to it.

Here is what I tried...

```
  //necessary imports over here 

    class Test extends javax.swing.JFrame 
  {
     public static void main(String args[]) throws MalformedURLException, IOException 
   {

  Test inst = new Test();
  inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  inst.setVisible(true);
  JPanel jp=new JPanel();   
  BufferedImage pic = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://www.swpc.noaa.gov/SWN/g_curr.gif"));
  JLabel label1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(pic));

  jp.add(label1);
  jp.setVisible(true);
  inst.add(jp);
  inst.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  inst.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
  inst.pack();
  inst.setSize(300,300);

    }
}
```

This code is not that efficient but it atleast gives you the output.

Hope it helps

Comment: Why are you too calling `setBounds(...)`? If you're going to give advice, at least show the original poster proper use of layout managers.

Comment: yes I agree with you. I should have omitted that in my code. Thanks for pointing it out. I will keep such things in mind while posting an answer henceforth.