# How to adjust Image size inside jLabel in JAVA Netbeans?

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel

I have a very big image but I want to resize it inside jLabel in Netbeans using jLabel properties. Please help me if possible.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22679717/resizing-image-to-fit-in-jlabel/22680573#22680573), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010803/java-swing-resize-imageicon-according-to-jlabel/18011430#18011430), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351186/resizing-jlabel-imageicon-with-html/18352000#18352000), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698271/how-to-make-jlabel-with-image-fill-borderlayout-center/11698479#11698479). The short answer is, you'll need to get your hands dirty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Image.getScaledInstance(...)` method to scale the image to your desired size.

Then you create an `ImageIcon` using the image and add the Icon to the `JLabel`.

Edit:

You can also try using Darryl's [Stretch Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/). Using this class the Icon will resize dynamically as frame resizes if you use an appropriate layout manager.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @VipulKumar For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22679717/resizing-image-to-fit-in-jlabel/22680573#22680573), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010803/java-swing-resize-imageicon-according-to-jlabel/18011430#18011430), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351186/resizing-jlabel-imageicon-with-html/18352000#18352000), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698271/how-to-make-jlabel-with-image-fill-borderlayout-center/11698479#11698479). The short answer is, you'll need to get your hands dirty

Comment: @Camickr Where's the link to your resizable icon?

Comment: Also [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html)

Comment: @VipulKumar, `Can you give an example?` - I gave you the class and method to use. You can read the API to see what the paramters are. You can also search the forum or web yourself for examples. You can't program if you don't learn to use the API and the resources of the web yourself. Don't rely on other to read the API for you.

Comment: I am a beginner. So how can I do this in an easy way? Remember, I am using Netbeans.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you are a beginner, you still need to learn how to read the API. What part about the API do you not understand?. I have never used an IDE like Netbeans so I don't know how you do this. Learn how to write code without depending on the IDE then you learn how to use Java and not the IDE.

Comment: @VipulKumar there so many tutorials are there . Check it . So you can also get some idea and you may become expert. Try your self.