# how to properly save a picture path in a database and assign it into a button?

Tags: java, database, swing, jfilechooser

How can I know the path of the picture that will be store in this button. Also, what type of picture will you recommend me to upload in this button ?

```
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();              
            int result = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

            if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {              
                try {
                    File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                    btnNewButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(file)));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can i know the path of the picture that will be store in this
>   button

This can be easily done by calling [File.getPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getPath%28%29) method:

```
File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
System.out.println(file.getPath());
```

Additionaly you can store this path *in* the button through [JComponent.putClientProperty(Object key, Object value)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#putClientProperty%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29):

```
File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
btnNewButton.putClientProperty("imagepath", file.getPath());
```

> what type of picture will you recommend me to upload in this button ?

It can be JPG, PNG, BMP, WBMP and GIF, as per [javax.imageio package description](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html). Be aware Java doesn't support ICO format natively: [Adding image to JButton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12034691/1795530)

Comment: thank you so much for your simplified answer sir . thanks for helping beginners like me :D

Comment: last question , I saved the imagepath in the database, then how can i set it to the same button when i navigate to the table row containing the path . thanks in advance =)

Comment: @dens14345 that's hard to say without seeing your code. Maybe you should post this in a different question, including relevant code and description of your goal and problem.