# java - Swing image not loading

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel

Whenever I try to add this image all I get is a blank jFrame. I am hoping some one can tell me what I am doing wrong. Also I have done a system.out.println on the image and it is getting loaded.

```
        BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("image.jpg"));


        javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));            
        jLabel1.add(jLabel2);
        jLabel1.repaint();
```

Comment: Hope this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230) can help you a bit on this path :-) along with this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372350/1057230) !!!! Though what is this **jLabel1** thingy ?

Comment: its a javax.swing.JLabel

Comment: @maxinfet I thik Andrew's asking what's the need to add one label to another...

Comment: @Mad I think Andrew's watching, rather than asking. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class LabelJarSample {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String title = "JLabel Sample";
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Container content = frame.getContentPane();
    content.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Text Label");
    content.add(label1);

    Image warnImage = ImageLoader.getImage(LabelJarSample.class, "Warn.gif");
    Icon warnIcon = new ImageIcon(warnImage);
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel(warnIcon);
    content.add(label2);

    JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Warning", warnIcon, JLabel.CENTER);
    content.add(label3);

    String htmlLabel = "<html><sup>HTML</sup> <sub><em>Label</em></sub><br>"
        + "<font color=\"#FF0080\"><u>Multi-line</u></font>";
    JLabel label4 = new JLabel(htmlLabel);
    content.add(label4);

    frame.setSize(300, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}




final class ImageLoader {

  private ImageLoader() {
  }

  public static Image getImage(Class relativeClass, String filename) {
    Image returnValue = null;
    InputStream is = relativeClass.getResourceAsStream(filename);
    if (is != null) {
      BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
      ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      try {
        int ch;
        while ((ch = bis.read()) != -1) {
          baos.write(ch);
        }
        returnValue = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(
            baos.toByteArray());
      } catch (IOException exception) {
        System.err.println("Error loading: " + filename);
      }
    }
    return returnValue;
  }
}
```

ref:http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/LabelwithImage.htm

note: also check the image location path is correct

Comment: its final class scroll below the code block . try refered url .

Comment: Thank you so much, I figured out what I was doing wrong. I was forgetting to set the size of the label.

Comment: That's a lot of effort, when something like [`ImageIO.read(URL)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.net.URL%29) will work just as fine - IMHO

Comment: @maxinfet You're using a `null` layout??? Gee, like that wasn't important information :P