# Displaying an image in a JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe

I am currently learning Java, and I am stuck with something at the moment.

I was looking for a way to add an image to my JFrame.
I found this on the internet:

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("path & name & extension");
JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(image);
```

And after implementing it to my own code, it looks like this (this is only the relevant part):

```
class Game1 extends JFrame
{
    public static Display f = new Display();
    public Game1()
    {
        Game1.f.setSize(1000, 750);
        Game1.f.setResizable(false);
        Game1.f.setVisible(true);
        Game1.f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Game1.f.setTitle("Online First Person Shooter");

        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Meneer\\Pictures\\image.png");
        JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(image); 
        add(imageLabel);
        }
}

class Display extends JFrame
{
}
```

When running this code, it doesn't give me any errors, but it also doesn't show the picture. I saw some questions and people having the same problem, but their code was completely different from mine, they used other ways to display the image.

Comment: keep `setVisible(true)` after `add(imageLable)`..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do this after creating `Jlabel`

```
imageLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 400, 400);
imageLabel.setVisible(true);
```

also set the layout to JFrame

```
Game.f.setLayout(new FlowLayout);
```

Comment: @alex2410, don't bother. The OP thought this is the best answer ;)

Comment: It did alex2410. Thanks for this answer AJ :)!

Answer (score 8):

1. You don't need to use another `JFrame` instance inside the `Game` `JFrame`:
2. Calling `setVisible(flag)` from the constructor is not preferable. Rather initialize your `JFrame` from outside and put your `setVisible(true)` inside event dispatch thread to maintain Swing's GUI rendering rules using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)`
3. Do not give size hint by `setSize(Dimension)` of the `JFrame`. Rather use proper layout with your component, call `pack()` after adding all of your relevant component to the `JFrame`.
4. Try using `JScrollPane` with `JLabel` for a better user experience with image larger than the label's size can be.

All of the above description is made in the following example:

```
     class Game1 extends JFrame
    {
       public Game1()
      {
         // setSize(1000, 750);  <---- do not do it
         // setResizable(false); <----- do not do it either, unless any good reason

         setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         setTitle("Online First Person Shooter");

         ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Meneer\\Pictures\\image.png");
         JLabel label = new JLabel(image);
         JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(label);
         scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
         scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
         add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         pack();
      }

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

           @Override
           public void run() {
              new Game1().setVisible(true);
           }
        });

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the label to the wrong `JFrame`. Also, move the `setVisible()` to the end.

```
import javax.swing.*;
class Game1 extends JFrame
{
    public static Display f = new Display();
    public Game1()
    {
        // ....
        Game1.f.add(imageLabel);
        Game1.f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try to use image from resources, and not from hardcoded path from your PC 
You can look in here, where sombody asked similar question about images in Jframe:
[How to add an ImageIcon to a JFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011705/how-to-add-an-imageicon-to-a-jframe)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in next you add your `JLabel` to `Game1` but you display another Frame(`Display f`). Change `add(imageLabel);` to `Game1.f.add(imageLabel);`.

Recommendations:

1)according to your problem: `Game1` extends `JFrame` seems that `Display` is also a frame, use only one frame to display content.

2) use `pack()` method instead of `setSize(1000, 750);`

3)call `setVisible(true);` at the end of construction.

4)use [`LayoutManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) to layout components.