# How to display a picture on JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

I'm doing this exercise where I'm supposed to write a program that simulates a race between two cars.

I've created a `JFrame` and added two rectangles that are supposed to be the tracks.

But I can't insert the cars. I have googled and tried some solutions but it just doesn not work out.

Here is my code.

```
public class Race extends JComponent {
private ImageIcon image;
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    g.fill3DRect(30, 150, 530, 55,true);
    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    g.fill3DRect(30, 250, 530, 55, true);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fill3DRect(90, 130, 12, 189, true);
}
public static void main(String[] a) {
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
    window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.getContentPane().add(new Race());
    window.pack();
    window.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Where and how can I add two pictures?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying an image in a JFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20098124/displaying-an-image-in-a-jframe)

Comment: `I've created a JFrame and added two rectangles that are supposed to be the tracks` - well if you can draw rectangles, then you can draw images, just use the `Graphics.drawImage(...)` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would add a image into your JFrame

```
frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Path/To/Your/Image.png")));
```