# Resources used by a jar

Tags: java, swing, jar, resources

I have a runnable jar (swing GUI) that uses a lot of resources (Videos, images, texts) and I don't know exactly what is the best way to access these rsc. Now I'm putting all my ressouces in `C:\` directory, but when I'm changing the machine I have to transfer all ressources manually to the appropriate directory.

Comment: put them inside jar or to web

Comment: Hopefully this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230), might be of some help. But if you doing manually, then this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372350/1057230), might be able to put some more light on the topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual approach is to package the resource files in the JAR, typically in or under the same "directory" as the package of the class in question

```
- com
  - example
    - MyClass.class
    - resources
      - icon.png
```

and then in `MyClass` you can use `this.getClass().getResource("resources/icon.png")` to access a resource as a `java.net.URL` or `getResourceAsStream` to access it as an `InputStream`.