# Unable to find icon image using loadIcon() and getProperty()

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, imageicon

I have the following statement and it's giving me a Null pointer exception:

```
Icon settingIcon =
   GUIUtilities.loadIcon(
      context.getProperty( "sys.setting.icon.small" ));
```

I'm trying to debug it, but I'd like to know what the directory structure is like at the moment it's trying to find the property. Is it possible to find out where the compiler is searching through at the moment of the error?

Right now, I'm falling back to using (with default.png being at the root folder: /Users/bigbitecode/Documents/workspace/sys client_a/):

```
Icon saveIcon = new ImageIcon("default.png");
```

Some helpful information:

- I have loaded the property successfully with the following info:
  at the file path: /Users/bigbitecode/Documents/workspace/sys client_a/sys-client/gui.prop

```
    #sys menu bar icon
    copa.setting.icon.small=icon/16x16/setting.png
```

- The file I'm trying to get is located at:
  /Users/bigbitecode/Documents/workspace/sys client_a/sys-client/resources/icon/16x16/settings.png
- The pathfile of the current code I have is at:
  /Users/bigbitecode/Documents/workspace/sys client_a/sys-client/src/sysClient/data/gui/sysClient.java

Comment: I hope you hadn't missed [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372350/1057230), from the links provided in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [embedded-resource](/questions/tagged/embedded-resource).  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

The likely path needed for `getResource()` is `/icon/16x16/settings.png`

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. I tried referencing the resources with getResource, but I seem to always be hitting at a null with the following code:

    URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/resources/icon/16x16/settings.png");
        Icon openFileIcon = new ImageIcon(url);

Comment: Do a `jar -tvf the.jar` to confirm it is where you expect.

Comment: I did a grep, and noticed that settings.png was not included. What does this mean? I have it all inside the resource folder, but it doesn't show up on the final .jar. Is there a way to include all the images?

Comment: *"I have it all inside the resource folder,"*  You seem to presume I know a lot about your IDE & build environment, that I actually don't.  Tip: At times like this, more detail is better than less.  ;)