# Background not showing up

Tags: java, swing, background, jframe, jpanel

The background I have made is not showing up, which is a big problem for me. Heres the code:

```
//Package and imports...

public class startScreen extends JFrame
{
    public static asteriod asteriod = new asteriod();
    static JFrame Screen = new JFrame("Stars");
    static boolean isShown = (boolean) Screen.isVisible();
    static heart heart = new heart();
    public static JPanel jpanel = new JPanel(); 
    static Random rand = new Random();
    static int suptogus = rand.nextInt(20)+1;
    static enemy enemy = new enemy();
    static player player = new player();
    static JLabel creatoranddate = new JLabel("Copyright 2013© All rights reserved.");
    public static int HEALTH = 100;
    public static int health = 50;

    public startScreen() 
    {
        super("Stars");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        Screen.setContentPane(new JPanel() 
        {
            Image image = ImageIO.read(new File("src/stars/optionsBackground.png"));
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
            {
                 super.paintComponent(g);
                 g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 700, 600, this);
            }
        });
        creatoranddate.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
        creatoranddate.setForeground(Color.WHITE.brighter());
        Point location = creatoranddate.getLocation();
        System.out.println("Located JLabel, at position " + location);
        add(creatoranddate);
        //adds background picture
        try{
            //adds logo
            JLabel logo = (new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("src/stars/logo.png")))));
            add(logo);
            System.out.println("Successfully added logo.\n");
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Failed to display logo. This is prone for the Stars.jar program.\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
            JLabel enemyLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("src/stars/enemyLabel.png"))));
            JLabel playerLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("src/stars/playerLabel.png"))));
            playerLabel.setForeground(null);
            enemyLabel.setForeground(null);
            enemyLabel.setBounds(0, 0, 700, 600);
            playerLabel.setBounds(20, 20, 700, 600);
            JLabel player = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("src/stars/playerSprite.png"))));
            JLabel enemy = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("src/stars/enemySprite.png"))));
            player.setForeground(null);
            enemy.setOpaque(true);
            player.setBounds(0, 0, 700, 600);
            enemy.setBounds(0, -32, 700, 600);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getVersion(String str)
    {
        return str = "Version InDev 2.0";
    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {

    }
}
```

The problem is all the code that is right below the declaration of `super("Stars");` to the end of the `paintComponent` method. I don't know whats going on, and if I even `throw IOException`, it still does not show the background image.

Comment: Tristen: you will learn that you're far better off testing problem code in isolation in a simple program. This way you can see if the problem is with reading in the image file or one of rending. So I suggest you do some debugging by dividing and conquering.

Comment: Use standard Java naming conventions. Your code is too hard to read. Class names should start with an upper case character. Variables names should start with a lower case character. Your code is inconsistent. You also should not be using static variables. Variable names like "HEALTH" and "health" are also confusing. Don't use case to differentiate variables.

Comment: Too true, as said in above comments. Moreover, had you tried to override the [getPreferredSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getPreferredSize()), as well along with `paintComponent()`. Make it return some valid Dimension object, something like `repturn (new Dimension(300, 300));`. I guess that will do, if you had added your resources in the right sense to the project :-) [For example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372350/1057230)

Comment: Moreover, you are re-initializing your `JFrame` by writing `static JFrame Screen = new JFrame("Stars");`, even though your class extends `JFrame` itself. Hence you should remove that line and use `setContentPane(new JPanel() {...})`, instead of `Screen.setContentPane(new JPanel(){...})`