# How to reference a local image in java?

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource, imageicon

```
jLabel5.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("./i/login.png"));
```

I'm trying to reference that image. The path is correct, and the image actually exists. When I use the full path (I.E. "C:/ blah blah" it works, but this doesn't?

The image folder is in the bin folder.

Comment: It all depends on the directory which the Java application is started from. We don't know anything about your directory hierarchy. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: The commented code will work in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372350/1057230), if your directory structure adheres to the one described n the same answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//This will retuns the URL of the image file inside your project
  this.getClass().getResource("/i/login.png");
```

So, your code will be :

```
URL imageUrl = this.getClass().getResource("/i/login.png");
jLabel5.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(imageUrl));
```

If the image is outside your current package, start the path with `/i/login.png`, else, don't need the `/`.

Comment: It must be stated that this solution (and a very good, portable one it is) depends on the image being in `this`'s jar file or otherwise on the classpath.

Comment: @Chase:Does your directory to the image is right? Check it please.

Comment: line 160: jLabel5.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(imageUrl));

Comment: @Chase: That means it can't find the specific *source*, When this happens, it returns null, hence the `NullPointerException`, check the directory again and don't forgot about case *sensitivity* in file names.

Comment: It's all correct, and lowercase... This doesn't make any sense lol.

Comment: @Chase: ask another question about that, and post your codes with it maybe it'll be solved ;)