# Include image inside a Java code

Tags: java, image

I'm using Dr. Java as a compiler for Java. I am trying to include an image inside my code. I'm building my first GUI program.

This is the code I used:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test{
public static void main(String[] args){

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Program");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

JPanel primary = new JPanel();
primary.setBackground(color.green);
primary.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));

JLabel label = new JLabel("Tesing the program");

primary.add(label);
frame.getContentPane().add(primary);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Lets say there's a file on my desktop called *image.gif* and I want to include this image in my code.

1. Can I store images as variables to use them in my code?
2. Where is the image usually stored in a java program and how can I refer to it?
3. Is an image a form of object?
4. What is the code to include the image I have in the program I am writing on Dr. Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Can I store images as variables to use them in my code?
```

yes you can. by using this command: `ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("C:\image.gif");`
(instead of C:\image.gif you must write your image location)

> Where is the image usually stored in a java program and how can I
>   refer to it?

`imageicon` helps you to show your image and put it where you want.

> Is an image a form of object?

everything in java is an object, except primitive types.

> What is the code to include the image I have in the program I am writing on Dr. Java?

first you must place your image somewhere you wanna refer to. and then define it as I told. and use how you want according the references.

Comment: *except a char, an int,a float and a double number* you mean *except a primitive type*. Also, your answer to the first question would be better if instead of using a direct URL to the file you show how to load the file from local resources in the application using `getResourceAsStream`. Apart of that, good answer.

Comment: You can start your research about using `getResourceAsStream` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2308188/1065197)

Comment: The tutorial shows how to load the image as a resource. Read the tutorial for the basics.

Answer (score 3):

> Im building my first GUI program.

Start by reading the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) on `Creating a GUI With Swing` for all the basics and lots of working examples.

> I want to include this image in my code.

You can start with the section on `How to Use Icons`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Can I store images as variables to use them in my code?
```

Yes, images are usually stored as variables.

```
Where is the image usually stored in a java program and how can I refer to it?
```

Images, basically are termed as application resources, that are used to provide some information, apart from text displayed on the `GUI`

You can have a look at [working with Images](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html) and this simple [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11372350/1057230)

As you deploy an application, `Images` used in the application are often embedded into the `JAR` file, along with the rest of the application. This answer, might can give you more information, as to how to [add a resource to the project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230)

Answer (score 1):

Or you could serialize a **java.awt.image.BufferedImage** under a class name and store it with the binaries in a **resources folder**, but why not simply **properly structure your applications folders**.

**java.awt.Toolkit** *obtained from the swing or awt container* is used to acquire images
the **java.awt.Graphics** object is used paint images onto the container and is also obtained through a method on the gui container you wish to paint on.

Another more complex imaging file manipulation system is in core java api
called **javax.imageio**