# how to put picture in from injavax.swing

Tags: swing

How can I reflect picture/image file in JFrame? Is there any component in javax.swing or java.awt?

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
frame.setLayout( new GroupLayout( getContentPane() ) );
frame.setSize( new Dimension( 600, 480 ) );
frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null ); 
frame.getContentPane().setBackground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );

// add Image container !!!

frame.setVisible( true )
```

Comment: Use a `JLabel` with an `ImageIcon` ?

Comment: Or you can also draw on top of any `JComponent`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372350/1057230) :-)

Comment: @Robin thx, man! I'd thought about it!