# How can i insert ImageIcon in panels?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, imageicon

I have four panels and I want to add images to these panels.
When I click on the start button, each panel need to change 4 images.
I making test program for Poker.
Images are placed in Card folder(root) and are called
1.png, 2.png, 3.png.... 52.png.

I am beginer in java programming and my question may sound stupid. I am encountering a `NullPointerException`

**Code:**

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Display extends Thread{
    private JPanel [] paneli;
    private JLabel slika;

    public JPanel[] getPaneli() {
        return paneli;
    }

    public void setPaneli(JPanel[] paneli) {
        this.paneli = paneli;
    }

    public JLabel getSlika() {
        return slika;
    }

    public void setSlika(JLabel slika) {
        this.slika = slika;
    }

    public void run(){
        JLabel [] labele = new JLabel[4];
        for(int i =0; i<paneli.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<labele.length; j++){
                slika.setIcon(new ImageIcon("card\\" + (i+1) + ".png"));
                labele[j].add(slika);
                paneli[i].add(labele[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace so we know what line is failing? For instance, is `paneli` ever getting initialized with `setPaneli`?

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372350/1057230), more info can be found on the [info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) page of `embedded-resource` :-)

Comment: first the paneli is not initialized. This should mean that when you call `paneli.length` in your code, a nullpointerexception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the image icon as follows:

```
slika.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/card/" + (i+1) + ".png"));
```

Comment: private JButton getBtnStart(){
  if(btnStart==null){
   btnStart = new JButton("Start");
   btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
     JPanel [] p = {panel, panel_1,panel_2, panel_3};
     d= new Display();
     d.setPaneli(p);
     d.start();
    }
   });
   btnStart.setBounds(22, 246, 97, 65);
   }
  return btnStart;
 }