# Making an image show up in Java

Tags: java, image, swing, bufferedimage

I've been struggling to get an image to show up for some time now. Ive read a few different things, and all of them seem to have different ways of showing images. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm trying to make a program that uses 2 classes to make a picture show up in a frame. I guess what I don't understand still is what a Graphics object is, what a Graphics2D object is and how its different, and what method from what class do I call in order to make an image show up. Here is my code:

public class Smiley {

```
private BufferedImage smileyFace;
private Graphics2D renderWindow;
private Dimension smileyPosition;
private File smileyFile;

public Smiley() {

    try{
    smileyFile = new File("C:\\Users\\MyName\\Desktop\\smiley.png");
    smileyFace = ImageIO.read(smileyFile);
    } 
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("There was an error finding or reading the file \" smiley.png.\"");
    }

    MainScreen.graphicPane.drawImage(smileyFace,50,50, null);
}
```

and the second class:

public class MainScreen extends JFrame{

```
public static MainScreen ms;
public static Graphics2D graphicPane;

public static void main (String[] args){
    MainScreen ms = new MainScreen();
    Smiley newSmiley = new Smiley();
}

public MainScreen(){
    super("Main Screen Window");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setSize(500,800);
    this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
    graphicPane = (Graphics2D) this.getContentPane().getGraphics();
}
```

}

the program compiles with no errors and nothing is reported back to me about not finding the file.

Comment: Please have a look at this answer, regarding, how to [__add images manually to a Java Project__](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372350/1057230), though, if you looking for some `IDE-Integrated Development Environment` help, please refer this thread, regarding how to [__add images to Java Project__](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230). Hope it helps you in some way :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your going to need some sore of `paint` method. For that you will require a Component to paint on. You need to learn a GUI framework, like Swing. There are clear compoents you can paint on like a `JPanel`. With that panel you need to override its `paintComponent` method.

The `Graphcics` object is what the component uses to actually paint the graphic onto the component.

The `Graphics2D` object just extends the capabilities of the Graphics object.

You should take a look at the [**Swing tuorial**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and the [**Graphics toturial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

To get your program running though you would do something like this

```
public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
    BufferedImage smileyFace;

    public DrawPanel() {
        try{
            smileyFile = new File("C:\\Users\\MyName\\Desktop\\smiley.png");
            smileyFace = ImageIO.read(smileyFile);
        } 
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("There was an error finding or reading the file \" smiley.png.\"");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(smileyFace,50,50, this);
    }

    @Override 
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return new Dimension(500, 500);
    }
}
```

Then you can instantiate that panel in another class, adding it to a JFrame to run it

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtiliites.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame  = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new DrawPanel());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling this in your constructor for your Smiley class.

```
 MainScreen.graphicPane.drawImage(smileyFace,50,50, null);
```

If you are going to paint the image yourself you need to override `paintComponent()` in a component that gets added to your main screen.

Or just add the image to a `JLabel` that you added to the main screen.

Answer (score 2):

You draw image in wrong way.

For using `drawImage()` you need to use that in `paintComponent()` method of `JComponent`(for example `JPanel`), examine next code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.beans.Transient;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Example extends JFrame {


    public Example() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new Smiley());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Example();
    }

    class Smiley extends JPanel{

        private BufferedImage smileyFace;

        Smiley(){
            try {
                File smileyFile = new File("C:\\Users\\MyName\\Desktop\\smiley.png");
                smileyFace = ImageIO.read(smileyFile);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out
                        .println("There was an error finding or reading the file \" smiley.png.\"");
            }

        }

        @Override
        @Transient
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(smileyFace.getWidth(),smileyFace.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(smileyFace, 0,0, this);
        }

    }
}
```

or you can add your image to `JLabel` and that do all for you, change `Smile` class like next:

```
class Smiley extends JPanel{

    Smiley(){
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\MyName\\Desktop\\smiley.png");
        JLabel l = new JLabel(icon);
        add(l);

    }

}
```

ALso read more about [customPaintings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).