# Why doesn't paintComponent(Graphics g) of JPanel run?

Tags: java, swing, awt

During my experience before, the **paintComponent(Graphics g)** of a panel will run when I just initial it and I can make it to repaint by calling repaint() method. But my demo below doesn't work like my experience. What's wrong with it?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;



public class BackgroundTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BackgroundTest backgroundTest = new BackgroundTest();
        try {
            backgroundTest.createUI();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void createUI() throws IOException{
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Background Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

        JLabel backgroundLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("background.png"));       
        JPanel imagePanel = new ImagePanel();
        imagePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(626, 434)); // it's the size of house.png
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(imagePanel);
        backgroundLabel.add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);


        mainPanel.add(backgroundLabel); 
        frame.add(mainPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);   

        frame.getContentPane().add(backgroundLabel,BorderLayout.CENTER);    
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }   

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            System.out.println("I'm not be run");
            super.paintComponent(g);
            BufferedImage image = null;
            try {
                image = ImageIO.read(new File("house.png"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You add `scrollPane` to `JLabel` it isn't correct. What do you try achive?

Comment: Hopefully this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372350/1057230), might be able to help you :-) Just not related, but for extra information, this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JLabel` has no layout manager installed by default, meaning that anything your add to is never resized and therefore is never painted, Swing is smart that way

Try using something like...

```
backgroundLabel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

Don't load your images within the `paintComponent` method, paints may occur often and within quick succession to each other, anything that slows down the paint process will slow it down for everything

You should also avoid using `setPreferredSize` and instead, let the component decided based on what it knows, for example

```
class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage image = null;

    public ImagePanel() {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("house.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return image == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (image != null) {
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , it's so elaborate.

Answer (score 4):

> But my demo below doesn't work like my experience. What's wrong with
>   it?

never to load, provide any FileIO inside `paint`/`paintComponent`, prepare this `Object` as Local Variable, means code lines

```
BufferedImage image = null;
try {
    image = ImageIO.read(new File("house.png"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```